# Override a 2D array to input specific values

Tags: java, arrays, qr-code

I am still new to java so forgive any mistakes or failing to follow posting rules :) I am making a QR code for class and have been stuck on the same program for over a week. I need help understanding how to override my 2D array. What we are doing is creating a 2D array that is dim by dim of random 0s and 1s. I have this part down. I then also need override the output 2D array with the requirements in the method `setFinder`.

(I apologize for there being so much to read)

Here are the methods we need to define:

`createPattern` returns a new one-dimensional array the size of dim squared. The array should be filled with random 0's and 1's which are generated by a `java.util.Random` object constructed with the given seed.

`setGrid` takes in the dimension dim and instantiates a two-dimensional array size of dim by dim. The grid is then filled row by row from the pattern provided by the one-dimensional pattern passed in.

`getGrid` returns a representation of the grid member.

`addFinders` calls `setFinder` for each of the three finders (upper left, upper right, lower left) positions.

`setFinder` calls `fillSquare` for each border/box which will overwrite the existing grid with the Finder pattern described here, placing a finder in each of the upper left, upper right, and lower left corners of the grid. If a grid is null, it returns null. The upper left corner of a Finder pattern is given by the parameters `xPos` and `yPos` which are the column and row, respectively, in the class member grid.

- The output border is two pixels in width. All values are set to 1 (WHITE in the GUI).
- The next inner border is two pixels in width. All values are set to 0 (BLACK in the GUI).
- The next inner border is two pixels in width. All values are set to 2 (WHITE in the GUI).
- The innermost box is 3x3 pixels. All values are set to 3 (BLACK in the GUI).

`fillSquare` sets the specified color of a square given the dimension (length) and starting coordinates of the upper left corner of the square area. The border width is passed in but not used (oops!).

thank you!

Here is my code thus far:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QRCode {
    Random RD = new Random();
    private int[][] grid;

    public int[] createPattern(int dim, int seed){
        Random RD = new Random(seed);
        int[] pattern = new int[dim*dim];
        for(int i = 0; i < pattern.length - 1; i++){
            pattern[i] = RD.nextInt(-1,1)+1;
        }
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setGrid(int dim, int[] pattern){
        int x = 0;
        grid = new int[dim][dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = pattern[x];
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[][] getGrid(){
        return null;
    }

    public void setFinder(int xPos, int yPos){

    }

    public void addFinder(int dimension){

    }

    public void fillSquare(int startX, int startY, int width, int color, int helper){

    }
}
```

Comment: Sit down with a pencil and paper and work out how you would manually draw a two-dimensional grid following the rules you've given for the `setFinder` method.  Do this as many times as you need to work out the algorithm for the `setFinder` method.  To answer the question in your title, you code the line  `grid[i][j] = value;` for the appropriate values of `i` and `j`.

Comment: The paper and pencil actually helped me collect my thoughts! Thank you! Ive been working through it and have almost finished!

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve your problem step by step.

Either you solve it "top down" or "bottom up":

*Top down* means, you implement the outermost methods first and pretend that the methods they call just work. This would be

1. `addFinder`
2. `setFinder`
3. `fillSquare`

*Bottom up* means, that you implement the methods first that are called by others.

1. `fillSquare`
2. `setFinder`
3. `addFinder`

When you implement a method, look at the parameters that you need for the method(s) you have to call and figure out, how to calculate or get them.

Aside you could implement the `getGrid` method, this should not use any of the other methods.

When you are stuck with one method, come back to ask more detailed questions.